# Get 'dotnet publish' command used by Vs 2017

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-core, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-2.1

In a .Net Core +Angular project how do I publish it from command line getting the same result as publish from VS 2017?

tried

> dotnet publish --configuration Release --runtime win-x64

but not getting the same result,found lots of dll files not present in publish from VS

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to publish the project using the `netcoreapp2.1` framework without --`runtime win-x64` as below

```
dotnet publish --framework netcoreapp2.1 --configuration Release
```

Default publishing settings in VS 2017 will target framework as below

[image: VS 2017 Publish Settings]

Comment: I've added the path   -o bin\Release\PublishOutput  and seems to be what I was looking for.thanks